# Заменяются параметры в onclick при динамическом создании объектов <a/> JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, table

есть функция в HTML коде, она создаёт динамически таблицу для странички, и на элемент в таблице нужно поставить в процессе создания обработку события, onclick, таких элементов МНОГО в таблице, все с разными id по типу: linck01, linck02 ... и т.д.
Вот что пытался использовать

```js
a.addEventListener("click", function (){
    clickLink(packege, a, id);
})

a.onclick = function () {
    clickLink(packege, a, id);
};

//iter и i это те самые цифры
$("#links_d" + iter.toString() + i.toString()).click(function ()
{
    clickLink(packege, a, id);
});

var links_d = tr.childNodes[4];
links_d = links_d.getElementsByClassName("links")
links_d[0].onclick = function () {
    clickLink(packege, links_d[0], id.toString());
};
```

в первом и последнем добавляет, но отрабатывает так что на всех элементах висит функция с последними параметрами, а не теми что передались (packege, a, id), как передать в функцию индивидуальные параметры.

Comment: покажите html-код

Comment: и у вас на в конце строки добавления первого листенера нету точки с запятой. так и задуманно?

Comment: Эх, забыл я про существование того вопроса (хотя и отмечался в нём). В общем, мой ответ тут - это первый вариант из принятого ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема сводится к следующей ситуации:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  $("#link" + i).on("click", function() {
    clickLink(i);
  });
}

function clickLink(index) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

```html
<div id="link1">Link 1</div>
<div id="link2">Link 2</div>
<div id="link3">Link 3</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

где всегда будет выводиться 4, так как на момент вызова функции обработчика `i` как раз и равняется 4

Исправить это можно, например, "захватом" текущего значения `i`:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    $("#link" + i).on("click", function() {
      clickLink(index);
    });
  })(i);
}

function clickLink(index) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

```html
<div id="link1">Link 1</div>
<div id="link2">Link 2</div>
<div id="link3">Link 3</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, понял что нужно повторить js, на такой вещи застрял...

Answer (score 0):

Можно навесить обработчик через document, тогда не нужно будет навешивать обработчики на динамически созданные элементы. При таком подходе вообще не придется навешивать обработчик в цикле и проблемы со счетчиком не возникнет в принципе, а код будет меньше по объему и проще для понимания.

```
$(document).on('click', '.links', (e) => {
    let packege = 1; //вычисляем при необходимости
    clickLink(packege, e.currentTarget, e.currentTarget.id.toString());
});
```

Еще как вариант, вообще навесить обработчик по ссылке:

```
$(document).on('click', '.links', clickLink);
```

А всю логику получения параметров перенести в функцию clickLink, через неявно передаваемый объект event.

Если же очень хочется отставить все как есть, то самым быстрым решением будет использовать `let` вместо `var` при объявлении счетчиков в циклах.